# Kendo UI File Upload Delete File in Synchronous Mode

Tags: jquery, file-upload, kendo-asp.net-mvc, telerik-mvc

I'm using the Kendo UI file upload control for MVC, in synchronous mode.  Is there a way to include a button that will allow a user to delete a selected file?  I've attached a screenshot of how my control currently looks.  [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8XIL.png)

Below is the JQuery code:

```
<script>
   $('#fileUpload').kendoUpload({
     localization: {
     select: 'Select invoice to upload'
    },
   multiple: false,
   showFileList: true,
   success: function (e)
 {
 },
select: function (e)
{
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I figured it out.  There is a remove button, but it wasn't displaying in the browser because someone on our team -- the file upload control is for a project with several team members -- had styled it in such a way that it was hidden.